# Changing IntegerProperty[value: ] to just value

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am bind the value of number of items left in the factory.

```
private int item;
private SimpleIntegerProperty itemProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private SimpleIntegerProperty remainingItem = new Simple IntegerProperty();
private SimpleIntegerProperty soldItem = new Simple IntegerProperty();
```

in the constructor

```
this.item = item;
itemProperty.set(item);
soldItem.set(0);
remainingItem.bind(soldItem.subtract(item).multiply(-1));
//itemProperty.bind((soldItem.subtract(item).multiply(-1));
```

In the fxml file

```
<Text text="${controller.factory.remainingProperty.get()}">
```

when I try to  bind itemProperty it give invalid
when I try to display with remainingProperty ReadOnlyIntegerProperty with get method,it throws **EXCEPTION** in the main class.

I am trying to subtract the number of item from ***item***
and display it.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace in the question

Comment: u mean the whole code

Comment: No, I mean the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: @James_D can you please check?

Answer (score 3):

[Expression bindings](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) are not method calls; they have a different syntax. Here, assuming there is an appropriate `factory` property in the controller with the appropriate method defined (`remainingItemProperty()`), you should use

```xml
<Text text="${controller.factory.remainingItem}">
```

Comment: I still got that exception